# La clase Light es abstracta; no se puede instanciar

Tags: java, objeto

tengo un pequeño programa con interfaces donde deseo agregar un dispositivo '*Light*' en una coordenada en concreto dentro del mapa, para que se refleje.

Para poneros en contexto de como he realizado el código, os dejo un poco del mismo; para empezar tenemos la clase **Light.java**, la cual tenemos 3 funciones (*encender*, *apagar* y *ver estado*):

```
@ADevice(icon = "light")
public class Light extends Device implements ILight{
    private boolean light = true;
    
    public Light(String description, String name, boolean light) {
        super(description, name);
        light = light;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOn() {
        setOn();
    }

    @Override
    public void setOff() {
        setOff();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getState() {
        return this.light;
    }   
}
```

Seguimos con otra clase llamada **Device.java**:

```
public abstract class Device {
    protected String description;
    protected String name;
    private HashMap<String, Method> metodos;

    public Device(String description, String name) {
        this.description = description;
        this.name = name;
        this.init();
    }

    // Métodos...
}
```

Luego, tenemos una interfaz de *Java* llamada **ILight.java**:

```
public interface ILight {
    public void setOn();
    public void setOff();
    public boolean getState();
}
```

Ahora lo que tenemos es una clase llamada **Principal.java** donde se crea un método el cual deseo agregar un nuevo objeto (d) para crear '*Light*'.

```
Device d = null;
this.setMapa(new MapView());
this.getMapa().setId("mapa");
this.getMapa().setCenter(new Coordinate(38.0883, -0.724255));
this.setDevices(new HashMap<Marker, Device>());
// Luz
d = new Light("Luces del polideportivo","polideportivo",false);
this.mapa.addMarker(this.addDevice(d,new Coordinate(38.08617676979483, -0.7176315683413612)));
```

El fallo lo tengo en la creación del objeto '*d*' el cual me dice que es un objeto abstracto y no me deja instanciarlo. Le mando 3 valores(String, String, Boolean), tal cual lo he puesto en la clase **Light.java** pero ni con esas me deja. Seguramente será alguna tontería que me habré saltado o que no entienda muy bien ya que estoy *empezando a programar* con java y todavía me cuesta mucho.

Comment: si la clase Light hereda de Device por que creas el objeto `d` como Device?, deberias crearlo como `Light d=new Light(......)`, debes saber que una clase abstracta no se pueden instanciar,solo se ace uso de herencia

Comment: @Dramaturgo lo he corregido tal cual me has indicado y me sigue dando el mismo fallo. Aunque tiene lógica lo que has comentado.

Comment: Podrías agregar parte de la clase Device y la corrección que has hecho a tu pregunta

Comment: ¿Cómo es posible que tengas dicho error si la clase `Light` no está declarada como abstracta? Te sugiero que nos compartas el texto del error íntegramente.

Comment: Os pongo un poco más acerca del problema. El error que da es el siguiewnte:
*Light is abstract; cannot be instantiated
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)*

Comment: @Dramaturgo te publico el código de la clase **Device.java** solo lo básico ya que lógicamente dicha clase tiene más métodos.
```
public abstract class Device {
    protected String description;
    protected String name;
    private HashMap<String, Method> metodos;

    public Device(String description, String name) {
        this.description = description;
        this.name = name;
        this.init();
    }

    // Métodos...
}
```

Comment: @NatalioRabasco de ser asi, [adjunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/515207/edit) la clase principal,para ver como declaras los objetos y las instancias de tus clases,

Comment: @Dramaturgo Al final ya pude solucionar el error. En los imports, importé una clase que es del mismo nombre pero de diferente nombre. Al final, una pequeña tontería que me ha llevado tiempo solucionarlo :). Gracias igualmente a todos!